# Configuring Apache with Tomcat and phpmyadmin

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk, apache-2.4

We have a server with Apache 2.4, Tomcat 7 and phpmyadmin, all of them installed by source, no repository.

I connected Apache with Tomcat through the jk connector by doing:

```
JkMount  /* worker1
```

and I moved /phpmyadmin in the Apache DocumentRoot, but of course website/phpmyadmin will redirect me to Tomcat, but I dont want that. It works only if I comment out the JKMount line

So, how can I configure Apache with Tomcat and phpmyadmin so that /* requests are forwarded to Tomcat and /phpmyadmin directly served by Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to exclude the path you don't want proxied

```
JkUnMount /phpmyadmin worker1
JkUnMount /phpmyadmin/* worker1
```